# What could cause Windows Explorer to display the error that data couldn't be read from the source file or disk when attempting to copy a file?

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-explorer, data-transfer, copy

Recently, I was copying a folder containing multiple files from my internal hard drive to an external USB drive - both drives formatted with NTFS. All of the files were successfully copied - apart from one. When Explorer attempted to copy this particular file, the following error was displayed:

Cannot read from the source file or disk

I was able to open this particular file from my hard drive without issue, proving that the file itself wasn't the issue here. Interestingly, if I attempted to copy the file from its location on my internal drive to a separate folder on the same drive, the same error message was displayed. IN the end, I simply deleted the file, re-copied it to the same location on my internal drive from another backup source, and then copy it to its final destination on my external USB drive.

Just so that I know for future reference in the case that this re-appears - is there a known cause for this particular error? The filename didn't contain any special characters, and the USB drive can't be the issue (because the error was also displayed when copying the file to a folder on the same drive).

Answer (score 0):

A antivirus programm may have locked your file.
Sometimes Windows behaves weird when the file path gets too long.
Another application prevents the file from even being read.